# Как найти в строке слово и если оно там есть удалить его от туда?

Tags: jquery

Есть строка с таким содержимым `var str = "02:00,08:00,16:00,08:00,";`

Есть моя переменная с таким содержимым `var myStr = "08:00";`

Как проверить есть ли в переменной `str` значение как в `myStr` и если есть то удалить его с переменной str

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = "02:00,08:00,16:00,08:00";
const myStr = "08:00";

const result = str.split(",").filter(el => {
 return el !== myStr
}).join(",");;

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "02:00,08:00,16:00,08:00,";
var myStr = /08:00/g;
var newStr = str.replace(myStr, "").replace(/(,,)/g, ",").replace(/(,$)/g, "");
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Мои 5коп...

```js
var str = "02:00,08:00,16:00,08:00,";
var myStr = '08:00';
var re = new RegExp(',?' + myStr, 'g')
var newStr = str.replace(re, "")
console.log(newStr);
```